# How to copy information between MS Teams chats/channels

Tags: microsoft-teams

Our organization uses Microsoft Teams. I had very long conversation with one team member. I need to share it with another team member. If I click on "add people to chat", there is no possibility to share full history for chats which started as 1:1 chat, for some reason, so I cannot share it this way. I also cannot "select" all conversation and just copy-paste, since the selection is not selecting all and/or immediately disapears before "copying" into clipboard. The single way I found and which I saw as accepted answers somewhere, is screenshotting and sharing jpg files.

IIUC this should be professional, paid tool which should help teams to communicate and remove obstacles in communication. Screenshotting shouldn't be the valid way, I wouldn't expect this issue even from freeware obsoleted communicator(and it's not issue in any one I'm aware of). Is there a way in MS Teams?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your issue is more related to Teams product, which we do not support. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.

Comment: If I click on "what's new" within that "product" whatever it is, it say `What's new in Microsoft Teams... Note: Microsoft Teams ...`  What is the difference between "your" microsoft-teams and Teams by microsoft, which goes under name microsoft teams? Anyways, the one I'm talking about blue human icon with white T in it. And The link you provided is does not lead to any place you can ask anyone, as this is reserved only for admins, not users. So if you know where to get actual use for this product, please share.

Comment: We are the developer support team for Microsoft teams focused on helping developers resolve their issues. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.